# Firebase reference objects by ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Imagine I have 2 collections: musicians and albums. Is there a chance I can reference albums with musicians by ID so that musicians can have multiple albums and appear as an array for musicians? What would the query look like in Firebase 9 Firestore? For example, this is possible and achievable in MongoDB. What are the chances of referencing 2 collections in Firebase? I am looking forward to achieving something like a [Database Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/reference/database-references/) in MongoDB

[image]

Comment: Improve your question with what you have tried and the problem/error.

Comment: The code you shared is for the Firebase Realtime Database, while you seem to be asking about Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are complete separate and the API for one does not work on the other. To get started with Firestore, have a look at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: @JohnHanley this is exactly my question about how do I do this. The code sample is a generic [Firestore set query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This is the only example I found that has some sort of reference. Do you really think I was unable to find the link you shared me with?

Comment: I'm sorry if the link I shared is not what you expected Aleksandrs. The problem remains though that you shared code that uses the Realtime Database API, which won't work on Firestore - and I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish based on the description alone. It's much more likely that we can help if you show us what query you've already tried using Firestore's API.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the question with a schema. The question is how do I implement such a relationship (one artist has many songs AKA one to many) within firebase Firestore?

Comment: Firestore has a `Reference` field type that allows a field in a document to refer to another document. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

Comment: For clarity, the question states **I can reference albums** but there are no `albums` in your proposed schema; there are artists and songs only so we won't know how an `album` fits into that picture. For example, an Artist can have multiple albums and technically a song can appear on multiple albums as well. A simple solution is to have another collection of Albums containing documents (one per album). The documentId of each of those would be stored in an array within `Artist` and an array within `Song`. So if you get an artist or a song, you will also know the album; no query needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Reference` field type to add a reference to a document in a field. To use this, create a `DocumentReference` object for the destination:

```
const artistReference = doc(db, "artists", "beatles");
```

And then set this as the value of a field:

```
const songRef = doc(db, "songs", "get back");

await setDoc(songRef, {
  title: "Get back",
  artist: artistReference
});
```

Note that no referential integrity checks are performed by Firestore, so the above does not check whether the artist document exist - nor will it prevent deleting the artist document.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Frank. Quick question, how likely are people to do such implementations? Isn't it easier to just reference the ID as a string? If not, how would I query for this collection with the `where` function?

Comment: To query for a reference field, you pass a `DocumentReference` as the value to the `where()` call. --- I normally don't use reference values myself, but store the identifier of the target as a simpler field value. But that's a personal preference, not a general recommendation.